# Wait until Application.Calculate has finished

Tags: events, vba, excel

Can I force my vba script to wait until Application.Calculate has finished to recalculate all the formulas?

Comment: Add `DoEvents` after `Application.Calculate`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Further to my comments, you can use DoEvents with the `Application.CalculationState`. See this example

```
Application.Calculate
If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
    DoEvents
End If
'~~> Rest of the code.
```

If you want you can also use a `Do While Loop` to check for `Application.CalculationState`

I would also recommend see this link

**Topic**: Application.CalculationState Property

**Link**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220901%28v=office.12%29.aspx

**Quote From the Above Link**

> Returns an XlCalculationState constant that indicates the calculation state of the application, for any calculations that are being performed in Microsoft Excel. Read-only.

Comment: I relied on this example code as it is commonly provided on the internet but it does not work.  DoEvents will _not_ block until calculate completes and is effectively a no-op in your example code.

Comment: same here... I still see #REF, #N/A indicating that calculations were not completed although it exited the block...

Comment: @user65 Any alternative solution? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Siddharth, any idea when that one DoEvents is required? Any idea why only one at most should suffice?

Comment: @stenci: `DoEvents` is required when you want to pass the control to the operating system so that it can finish processing the events in its queue. Usually one is enough but you may issue more than one `DoEvents` in a loop to constantly pass the control back to ensure that all events in the queue are processed. For example between a copy and paste, one `DoEvents` will suffice. Where as in the above example, you may have to issue the same thing in a `Do While` loop.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Issuing one in a loop is a key here. Excel calculates asynchronously anyway even when you don't "pass the control". The DoEvents here is for you, not for Excel, so that you can wait without blocking the Excel UI.

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer did not worked for me because "DoEvents will not block until calculate completes and is effectively a no-op in your example code" I had the same issue. Finally [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998059/pause-vba-loop-until-sheet-is-recalculated) solution worked for me.

```
Do
    DoEvents
    Application.Calculate
Loop While Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone
```

In Manual calculation mode sometimes while loop goes into long running process. That is why added below line.

```
Application.Calculate
```

Comment: How would starting calculation over again on each iteration help speed up the loop's completion?

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe no-one has posted this solution, which would appear to be pretty much the definitive one ...

```
Do While Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone
    If Application.CalculationState = xlPending Then Application.Calculate
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
Loop
```

The Microsoft docu says that application.wait allows re-calculation to proceed in the background.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Calculate` did not work for me, I had to remove `Application.` and use this instead:

```
Do
    DoEvents
    Calculate
Loop While Not CalculationState = xlDone
```