# Excel VBA wait for Application.CalculateFull

Tags: excel, vba

When I call `Application.CalculateFull` and put a breakpoint at the next statement, I see in the status bar that processor processing after a while but has already reached the next line of code.

I checked the forum and people suggested to use `DoEvents`. In my case that's a problem as the worksheet has many formulas and some of them show wrong result after first run though formula is correct, so when I call the `CalculateFull` for the worksheet, it corrects it but doesn't wait.

If I use `DoEvents`, the `CalculateFull` doesn't update the worksheet.

So I am in a bind.

How can I wait for the processor to complete processing on `Application.CalculateFull` and only after that go to next line of code?

I used `Application.Wait` also but it seems to hold the processor and once released it starts calculation then, which doesn't solve my problem.

---

```
waittime (1000)
SendKeys "+^%{F9}", True
Application.CalculateFullRebuild
```

This is the code I use for now. When I put the breakpoint at the next line of code, I see that the `Application.calculatefullRebuild` takes a few secs and goes the next line and when I check the activesheet now, in another 2-3 sec I see in status bar Calculating (4 processors):xx% and after which the worksheet values are changed to the right values.

This is my issue. When `Application.CalculateFullRebuild` completes and goes to the next line, my worksheet results are still not accurate and only after a couple of secs the processors calculating statusbar message, the worksheet is updated.

How can I wait for this to complete, otherwise the remaining code will pick up wrong results.

Comment: could you maybe provide an image of what happens or something else so we can see what you mean

Comment: AFAIK, `.CalculateFull` isn't async so with a single-threaded environment like VBA it's very unlikely that the code jumps to the next line without finishing calculation :/ strange at least

Comment: Does your workbook use asynchronous functions? And why do you have to use CalculateFull rather than Calculate?

Comment: waittime (1000) SendKeys "+^%{F9}", True Application.CalculateFullRebuild

application.calculatefullRebuild takes a few secs and goes the next line and when I check the activesheet now, in another 2-3 sec I see in status bar Calculating (4 processors):xx% and after which the worksheet values are changed to the right values. When Application.CalculateFullRebuild completes and goes to the next line, worksheet results are still not accurate and only after a couple of secs the processors calculating statusbar message, the worksheet is updated. How to fix this

Comment: Application.Calculate works but the results in one of the worksheet   which has many formula does not give correct results and then reexecute Application Rebuild helps to correct the value but macro isn't waiting for the process to finish and going to next line

Comment: Does your workbook use any worksheet functions that are not native Excel Functions? If so what are they?

Answer (score 1):

So I believe that the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277034/wait-until-application-calculate-has-finished) has the answer you are looking for (modified slightly below to put it in a while loop):

```
Do While Application.CalculationState <> xlDone
     DoEvents
Loop
```

Sticking the above loop in your code right after starting the calculation process should be all that is required.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same solution as [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1866809/brad) extended by a timer to inform the user if things go wrong. I found that without triggering the Application.Calculate command (or CalculateFull) excel did not proceed calculating by the DoEvents allone.

```
Const MAXTIME_S = 10
Dim t As Double
t = Timer()

If Application.CalculationState <> xlDone Then Application.Calculate

Do While Application.CalculationState <> xlDone
    DoEvents
    If Timer() - t > MAXTIME_S Then Exit Do
Loop

If Application.CalculationState <> xlDone Then
    MsgBox "Calculation not done. Please restart this Macro.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Aktualisieren"
    Exit Sub
End If
```