# How to ensure Excel calculation is completed from within a VBA procedure

Tags: vba, excel

In an excel-spreadsheet user-defined functions are used to calculate basic results as spread-sheet matrices (cross-section values of composite elements).

```
Public Function XSValues(inputRange as Range) as variant
    [...]
    ' returns an array and used as matrix-formula (Ctrl-Shift-Enter)
End Function
```

These results are used within the spreadsheet on the one hand. Based on some values from these spreadsheet-results, on the other hand, a VBA-procedure is used to perform a relatively complex and time consuming calculation (static analysis of a structural model). This procedure is triggered by a button.

```
Public Sub Recalculate()
    [...]
    myValue = range("SomeXLResult").Value
    ' calculation
    ' notification updates
    ' drawing
    ' places different results into cells
End Sub
```

Now, my problems is, that the spread-sheet calculation is out of date, when the `Sub Recalculate` is triggered.
I found that in Excel 2016, the spread-sheet calculation is split into multliple threads. And experienced that user interaction sometimes is faster than spreadsheet calculation.

Therefore, I get depreciated values for further processing in the VBA-procedure.
My question is: **How to guarantee for updated values from spread-sheet ranges?**

Comment: Related questions, I found during further research: 

[Question 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277034/wait-until-application-calculate-has-finished)
and 
[Question 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354753/excel-vba-wait-for-application-calculatefull/41763774#41763774)

Comment: Well you already found the answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the solution as explained in your answer is working for you then great. I'm just wondering if you're aware of the application's `AfterCalculate` event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-aftercalculate-event-excel):

> This event occurs whenever calculation is completed and there are no
>   outstanding queries. It is mandatory for both conditions to be met
>   before the event occurs. The event can be raised even when there is no
>   sheet data in the workbook, such as whenever calculation finishes for
>   the entire workbook and there are no queries running.
>
> Add-in developers use the AfterCalculate event to know when all the
>   data in the workbook has been fully updated by any queries and/or
>   calculations that may have been in progress.
>
> This event occurs after all Worksheet . Calculate , Chart . Calculate
>   , AfterRefresh , and SheetChange events. It is the last event to occur
>   after all refresh processing and all calc processing have completed,
>   and it occurs after Application . CalculationState is set to xlDone .

It might be an easier implementation for you. The trick to access the application object's events is to declare it `WithEvents` in a class module. For the example, I've called the class *clsAppEvents*:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mApp As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub mApp_AfterCalculate()
    Debug.Print "Calc ended at: " & Now
    ConsumeAfterCalculate
End Sub
```

In your module, you'd simply have the calling and event handling code:

```
Option Explicit

Private mAppEvents As clsAppEvents
Private mEnableConsume As Boolean

Public Sub RunMe()
    Set mAppEvents = New clsAppEvents
End Sub
Public Sub ConsumeAfterCalculate()
    If mEnableConsume Then
        Debug.Print "Sub called at: " & Now
        mEnableConsume = False
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub ConsumeButtonClick()
    Debug.Print "Button clicked at: " & Now
    mEnableConsume = True

    'For demo purposes I'm just forcing a calculation on existing data.
    Sheet1.EnableCalculation = False
    Sheet1.EnableCalculation = True
End Sub
```

FYI, the debug results were as follows:

> Button clicked at: 25/10/2017 4:49:20 p.m.
>
> Calc ended at: 25/10/2017 4:49:22 p.m.
>
> Sub called at: 25/10/2017 4:49:22 p.m.

Comment: Thank You Ambie! Great and more straight-forward solution. I did not have the idea of creating a class that catches the AfterCalculate event!

Answer (score 1):

The following solution satisfies my needs:

When a button for recalculation is pressed, vba checks the current Excel calculation state. In case, calculation is done, the VBA-Procedure for calculation `Recalculate` is started directly. In case, calculation-mode is pending or calculating, then only the local worksheet-variable `p_RecalcButtonClicked` is set to true. When excel calculation is done, each worksheet fires the `Worksheet_Calculate` event **after** it was calculated. And so we can instruct Excel to `Recalculate` then.

As a safety measure, I kept the solution described in [the related two questions from the above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908493/how-to-ensure-excel-calculation-is-completed-from-within-a-vba-procedure#comment80763760_46908493) at the beginning of the sub `Recalculate` using the function `waitForRecalculation`. To avoid inactivity, I introduced a timer to tell the user, if calculation could not be finished within a given amount of time.

This is the code of the main worksheet:

```
' ##### Worksheet-Code

'''
' Private Worksheet-Variable to determine, 
' if the button was pressed prior to worksheet calculated-event
'
Private p_RecalcButtonClicked As Boolean


'''
' Procedure to handle Button Clicked 
' (either using a shape with a macro assigned or 
'  an Active-X-Button with this procedure as event handler: best is to use {Button}_MouseUp as {Button}_clicked is fired occasionally by excel itself)
'
Public Sub ButtonClicked()
    '
    ' depending on the calculation state ...
    '
    Select Case Application.CalculationState
        Case xlDone
            '
            ' ... all done, fine ...
            ' ... directly call the calculation procedure sub Recalculate
            '
            p_RecalcButtonClicked = False
            Recalculate
        Case xlPending
            '
            ' ... pending ...
            ' ... set local worksheet variable true in order to call sub Recalculate
            '     later, when the calculated-event was raised
            '
            p_RecalcButtonClicked = True
            '
            ' instruct excel to recalculate
            '
            Application.CalculateFullRebuild
            '
            ' now let excel perform until worksheet calculated event is raised
            '
        Case xlCalculating
            '
            ' ... calculating ...
            ' ... set local worksheet variable true in order to call sub Recalculate
            '     later, when the calculated-event was raised
            '
            p_RecalcButtonClicked = True
            '
            ' let excel continue until worksheet calculated event is raised
            '
        Case Else
    End Select
    
End Sub


'''
' worksheet calculation finished
' this event is raised AFTER calculation was finished
' (shold actually be named Worksheet_Calculated)
'
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    ' check if the RecalcButton was clicked 
    If p_RecalcButtonClicked Then
        p_RecalcButtonClicked = False
        Recalculate
    End If
End Sub

'''
' Recalculation
'
Public Sub wm_Recalculate()
        '
        ' wait for calculation to be done
        ' just in case...
        '
        If Not waitForRecalculation Then
            MsgBox "Press Ctrl+Alt+F9 for full recalculation", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Excel-calculation not done"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' [...] Your calculation here...
End Sub

'''
' Helper function to wait and do events until Excel-calculations are done
' returns true if calculation is done within the given time
'
Public Function waitForRecalculation() As Boolean

    Const MAXTIME_S = 10

    Dim t As Double
    t = Timer()


    ' in case of sql-async queries this might be required
    ' 
    ' Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
    
    '
    ' As a safety net,
    ' the second solution is to
    ' do System events until calculation is done
    '
    If Application.CalculationState <> xlDone Then
        Do
            DoEvents
            If Timer() - t > MAXTIME_S Then Exit Do
        Loop Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone
    End If

    '
    ' return true if calculations are done
    '
    waitForRecalculation = (Application.CalculationState = xlDone)

End Function
```