# VBA and Excel: Why does my TRIM script results in #VALUE on large data sets?

Tags: vba, excel, trim

The following script works on smaller data sets (less than 30k rows or so), but results in "#VALUE" errors for every cell in the selected range when the range is larger than that.

```
Dim FirstCell As Range, LastCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set LastCell = Cells(Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
      Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)

Set FirstCell = Cells(Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
      Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)

Set MyRange = Range(FirstCell, LastCell)
      MyRange.Select
      If MyRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    With Selection
        .Value = Evaluate("if(row(" & .Address & "),clean(trim(" & .Address & ")))")
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    MsgBox "Finished trimming " & vbCrLf & "excess spaces", 64
```

[VBA TRIM Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HpNp.jpg)

Comment: About how many cells are you changing with this code?  I just tested it on ~1.7 million cells and I didn't get any errors

Comment: 8,106,860 cells on my practice document.  That's 161,363 rows.

Comment: It seems to work up to about 70k rows.  Too much more than that, it just sets the value of every cell in the selected range to #VALUE.

Comment: What about copying the range (or at least sections of it) into a memory-based array, performing the trim, then copy that block back to the spreadsheet? Would probably be faster too.

Comment: I also tried setting MyRange = Selection (where I select the same range as the FirstCell to LastCell), and it works about half the time without giving me the same error.

Comment: Maybe a DoEvents [using this method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277034/wait-until-application-calculate-has-finished) might help? Have you also tried moving `ScreenUpdating` after you set the calculation property?

Comment: Perhaps try iterating through all columns in the range and performing the action on each column successively?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to replicate your issue, and using a variant array as shown below overcomes the issue for large data sets

```
Dim FirstCell As Range, LastCell As Range, MyRange As Range
Dim DataRange() As Variant
Dim lRows As Long
Dim lCols As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim value As String

Set LastCell = Cells(Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
      Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)

Set FirstCell = Cells(Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
      Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)

Set MyRange = Range(FirstCell, LastCell)
  MyRange.Select
  If MyRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  lRows = MyRange.Rows.Count
  lCols = MyRange.Columns.Count
  ReDim DataRange(1 To lRows, 1 To lCols)
  DataRange = MyRange.value
  For j = 1 To lCols
    For i = 1 To lRows
      DataRange(i, j) = Trim(DataRange(i, j))
    Next i
  Next j

  MyRange.value = DataRange

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
MsgBox "Finished trimming " & vbCrLf & "excess spaces", 64
```

For reference, I used this article to help come up with the answer: https://blogs.office.com/2008/10/03/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scan-a-large-range-in-excel/

Comment: Links can be broken in the future. Please copy-paste the information needed to answer the question into your post.Use the link only as a reference.

Comment: I have updated the answer to make it more clear that the link was for reference only, the answer is included above