# Pause VBA loop until sheet is recalculated

Tags: excel, vba, loops, refresh

I searched Google until page 10, but could not find a solution for this. 
 I have a loop in VBA, but want it to wait before proceeding until the sheet has recalculated.

What most people suggest is employ `DoEvents`. However, that does not work for me.

Here is my code so far, which does not wait until the sheet calculated:

```
Sub Replaceifrebalance() 
Dim x As Integer 

NumRows = Range("CF16", Range("CF16").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count 

Range("CF16").Select 

For x = 1 To NumRows 
    If Range("CF" & x).Value > 0 Then 
        Range("AW15:BF15").Select 
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 
        Selection.Copy 
        Range("AW1").Select 
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ 
        :=False, Transpose:=False 
        Range("AW" & 1 & ":BF" & 1).Copy Worksheets("Timeseries").Range("BI" & x & ":BR" & x) 

        Application.Calculate 
        If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then 
            DoEvents 
        End If 
    End If 

Next 

End Sub
```

Does anyone know a different solution than this one?:

```
  Application.Calculate 
    If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then 
        DoEvents 
    End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Do While` – `If` is of no use. For `If` the code will evaluate once and then move forward. `Do While` will keep it looping until the condition is satisfied.

```
Do
    DoEvents
Loop While Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone
```