# Excel VBA get cell value after recalculation

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that calculates various values based on a random value and would like to use the law of large numbers to converge to an average for each calculation.

I am thinking of using VBA to execute the calculation 1000's of times and store the values in a list for averaging at the end. My current testing code only stores the original value after each iteration. ie Safety1 does not change even though the value in R36 changes.

```
Dim Safety1(0 To 10) As Long


For i = 0 To 10

    Safety1(i) = Sheet34.Range("R36").Value
    Debug.Print Safety1(i)

Next i

myAverage = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Safety1)
```

myAverage should be the converging average.

R36 contains the sum of other ranges, which contain values based on `rand()`

If there is a better way to do this, i am happy to listen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That loop is going to loop the same cell data over and over again before the sheet recalcs. You need to look into a worksheet_change event  that calls a routine with a static or global variable that won't be erased between iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277034/wait-until-application-calculate-has-finished) resolved the problem. I needed to wait until the calculation process had completed before storing the value

Answer (score 0):

Please do sheet calculate like this:

```
Dim Safety1(0 To 10) As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False    

For i = 0 To 10
    Worksheets("Sheet34").Calculate
    Safety1(i) = Sheet34.Range("R36").Value
    Debug.Print Safety1(i)

Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
myAverage = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Safety1)
```