# Run a macro after certain cell values are calculated (When the cells are not in #VALUE error state)

Tags: excel, vba

### Background

I have a **macro number 1** which will

1. populate a range with formulas
2. turn the sheet to automatic calculation = true

When I **run macro number 1**, the cells will

1. first be populated with formulas (the formula are copied and pasted)
2. after several automatic refresh, the cells will go from #VALUE! to real values (because it takes time to fetch the data - it takes within 7 seconds)

I also have another **macro number 2** which

- does some operations based on the real values generated by **macro 1**

P.S. both macros will have EnvOff in the beginning and EnvOn in the end, EnvOff means turns of automatic calculation and screen update = false, and vice versa.

### The problem I face

I have difficulty **linking 2 macros together in 1 single macro** which **calls the 2 functions I mentioned above** in an error-free manner, because:

1. I tried using `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))`，so what I did in `macro_number_3` was:

```
macro_number_1
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00")) 'which I thought will let values refresh
macro_number_2
```

But turns out the formulas in `macro_number_1` is populated, but the values are not updating unless the whole `marco_number_3` ends. So the `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))` is useless here.

`marco_number_3` returns a `Type error` because `marco_number_2` do operations based on real values generated by `macro_number_1` (Note: `macro_number_1` populates the formula, but real values will show up only several seconds)

2. After experimentation, I discover that the values based on populated formulas will only refresh and show up when no existing macro is running.

### What I want to do

I want to link `macro_number_1` and `marco_number_2` together, so that `marco_number_2` will run after the values in `marco_number_1` have shown up. However, I can't use `marco_number_3` to put them in a same function, nor can I use `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Have you tried to call `Application.Calculate` after the formulas are written and before you start the processing?

Comment: some suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277034/wait-until-application-calculate-has-finished)

Comment: You can use `Application.OnTime` to schedule a macro to run at a specific time in the future.